# Why LXML ElementMaker breaks when I use an integer as attribute value?

Tags: python, lxml, decorator

I am trying to create a XML document with the help of LXML. I realized that 
`ElementMaker` breaks when I use an integer.

**Code**

```
from lxml.builder import ElementMaker
from lxml import etree

maker = ElementMaker()
maker.text(**{'label': 'my textarea'})    # works

maker.ratings(**{'points':5})             # breaks
```

**Error**

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lxml/builder.py", line 210, in __call__
    get(dict)(elem, attrib)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lxml/builder.py", line 197, in add_dict
attrib[k] = typemap[type(v)](None, v)
KeyError: <type 'int'>
```

**Why I cannot assign the attribute value as an integer?**

Comment: you cannot have integer values in XML. Try using `'points':"5"` and then convert the value to integer when you are parsing the data

Comment: @nish: Please add your comment as an answer in order to accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot have integer values in XML. 
You can enter data as string and convert is to the required format when you are parsing the data.

In your case try using `'points':"5"` and then convert the string to integer when you are parsing it